# How to know if a quadratic equation can be equal to zero?

Tags: quadratics

How to check by a fixed algorithm/formula for the possibility of these:
x^2 + x + 1 = 0      AND
2x^2 + 4x - 2 = 0  AND 
x^3 + 3 = 0

Comment: Do you mean *those* particular equations, or generic ones with arbitrary coefficients? Also, the 3rd one is not a quadratic.

Comment: Why not just use the Quadratic formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: *all* three of the siultaneously?  Use quadratic equation to solve one and see if it satisfies the others.  1st: $x=\frac {1\pm \sqrt {1-4}}{2} $ has no solution so the are no answers that will satisfied all three.